# contains() compares by value, not reference?

Tags: java

I was surprised to see that equals() is apparently overridden for `ArrayList<String>`. Because contains() in Collection<> apparently compares values, not references. Of course, for `Collection<Object>`, references would be compared. In the program below, shouldn't I get false on the second line?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    al.add("Obama");
    al.add("Reagan");
    al.add("Bush");
    al.add("Nyquist");
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("Bush");

    System.out.println("compares values? using constants " + al.contains("Bush"));
    System.out.println("compares values? using local variable " + al.contains(sb.toString()));
}

run:
compares values? using constants true
compares values? using local variable true
```

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Because Eclipse optimizes code at compile time such that `"ab" == "a" + "b";` is `true`, even though it shouldn't be. That is, if Eclipse sees two objects whose values are defined at compile time and are equal to each other, rather than store two different memory addresses, it combines them into one.

Comment: contains uses `Object.equals`; all Collection operations do so for equality unless noted to work otherwise.

Comment: Not related to the question, but do not use `StringBuffer`. Use the much better, API-identical `StringBuilder`. `StringBuffer` synchronizes similar to `Vector`.

Comment: I am using NetBeans 7.1 @pickypg. I intentionally used StringBuffer so that the same reference for "Bush" would not be shared if it were a constant.

Comment: @Anil - `StringBuilder` would behave exactly the same. It's not going to return a pointer to the internal string pool because it's constructing a new `String` from its internal buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly the output you should expect, and `Collection<Object>` would be no different.  All `Collection` types, unless specified otherwise, use `.equals(Object)`, and differing implementations violate the `Collection` contract.  (And to be clear, upcasting a `String` to an `Object` does not change the behavior of its `equals` method.)

There is some precedent -- see e.g. the `TreeSet` implementations, which use comparison-based equality, and `IdentityHashSet`, which uses reference equality -- but these should usually be used only when the two notions of equality match, or for significant and unusual need.

Answer (score 5):

[Javdaocs for List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) are you friend. `List.contains()` relies on `.equals()`:

> **boolean contains(Object o)**
>   Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

[`String.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) compares the `String`s contents (characters):

> **public boolean equals(Object anObject)**
>  Compares this string to the
>   specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is
>   not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of
>   characters as this object.

Comment: I did read javadocs for List contains(). I had seen the == which is a reference comparison :)

Comment: Just to be clear, `==` a *value* comparison. The ternary `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))` says that if `o` is passed in as `null` then return (boolean) whether `e` (an element) is null, otherwise return `o.equals(e)`. This is because otherwise it would cause a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

you can try System.out.println(sb.toString().equals("Bush")); in your class and see what it returns. It will return true. So in the second case it is returning/printing true.